# How to deploy django app on IIS error 403.14

Tags: python, django, iis, web-deployment, wsgi

I have a problem with deployment my Django application on IIS.
my `wsgi.py`

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault(
    'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE',
    'BETA.settings')


application = get_wsgi_application()
```

in my `settings.py` I have

```
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [some ip]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'BETA.wsgi.application'
```

my `__init__.py` is empty

in root derictory web.config looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="login.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument> 
    <handlers>
      <add 
        name="Python FastCGI" 
        path="*" 
        verb="*" 
        modules="FastCgiModule" 
        scriptProcessor = 'C:\Program Files\Python310\python.exe"|"C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py'
        resourceType="Unspecified"
       </configuration> requireAccess="Script"
        />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="BETA.wsgi.application">
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\Applications\HRtool\dev\wwwroot\BETA">

    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="BETA.settings">
  </appSettings>
```

in static web.config is next:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
        </handlers>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

But when I start my app on ISS i have another problem:

[image]

I am trying to enable Directory Browsing, but it doesn't help. In advance settings in Pool I have .Net 4.5. How to fix it ?

Comment: After you enable directory browsing, is there any other error code or message? All error message you show is only 403.14. Did you set default index page for the site? Add a default web page and enable it. Then check if there any more error.

Comment: Yes, now I have enable directory browsing, but I see only my folders and files in Project folder. Could you please tell me how to set and where this default pages and enable? my urls looks like: `path('',                views.loginPage,    name='login'),
    
    
    path('team_gpds/',      views.team_gpds,    name='team_gpds'),
    path('my_team/',        views.my_team,      name="my_team"),
    path('info/',           views.info,         name="info"),
    path('gpd/<pk>/',       views.gpd,          name='gpd'), 
    path('gpd_nevs/<pk>/',  views.gpd_nevs,     name='gpd_nevs'), `

Comment: You can set default page in Default Document module, not django. Just add the page in it.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5GBi.png

Answer (score 0):

If you revert all changes related to FastCGI and start cleanly with HttpPlatformHandler, you will see how smooth the experience is,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <httpPlatform stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\python.log" startupTimeLimit="20" processPath="C:\Users\<user name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe" arguments=".\mysite\manage.py runserver %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%">
        </httpPlatform>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Python/Django still takes care of everything including static files, and IIS/HttpPlatformHandler just passes requests on.

More details can be found from [my blog post](https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/running-django-web-apps-on-iis-with-httpplatformhandler/).